# Search Console showing pages with index.php? in the url

Tags: querystring

Google Search Console lists page urls that include a query string /`index.php?={some_page_name}`. I have not been to figure out why. This occurs with valid pages as well as some urls that have redirects. All of the redirects precede the `RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]` in the htaccess file.

I see this on virtually all of my Craft sites. Can anyone explain why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you add variables to the URL each URL will represent a different content so google will consider each one of them as a unique URL, if you do not want this behavior to happen you can replace these URL with post request ( so the variables are not listed in the URL )

hope this help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Salah! Having url parameters in not the issue here. Here is an example of what is happening: I have this url: /recipes/goat-cheese-fondue. It appears that way in my sitemap and Google indexes it just fine. However, in Search Console Google lists this as well: /index.php?p=recipes/goat-cheese-fondue, and tells me it did not index it because it found an alternate page with a proper canonical tag. The question is, how is Google getting  that url with the query parameter during a site crawl?

Comment: If he provided the website in question , we could find out the real issue.